# Why didn't Dronacharya kill Ghatotkacha with his divine weapons?

Tags: mahabharata, karna, dronacharya, ghatotkacha

Karna had to waste his shakti weapon on Ghatotkacha but at the same time Dronacharya was the leader of the army and he was well versed in almost all the divine weapons.

Why didn't Dronacharya kill Ghatotkacha with one of his divine weapons (divyAstra) instead of Karna wasting the only shakti-astra he had?